# How to use Select Case for Text String

Tags: excel, vba

I'd like to have a case that reads a text string such as "Net 75 from 1st of following month", if that cell contains this value it will do the following case.

My code works when the value is say "P" but once I make it long it no longer works?

```
  Option Explicit
  Sub CalcColB()

Dim x As Long
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    For x = 1 To Cells(Rows.Count, "F").End(xlUp).Row
       Select Case UCase(Cells(x, 6))
          Case "Net 75 from 1st of following month"
                Cells(x, 2).FormulaR1C1 = "=A2*1.8"
          Case "F"
               Cells(x, 2).FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-1]*1000"
          Case Else
               Cells(x, 2).Formula = "="""""
      End Select
  Next x
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Remove the `UCase` or change your text to be all caps.

Comment: There is a `UCase` in there, which converts everything to uppercase first. So it isn't matching `Net 75 from 1st of following month`, it's matching that phrase in all Caps.

Comment: Why not just use on formula:  `Range("B1:B" & Cells(Rows.Count, "F").End(xlUp).Row).Formula = "=IF(LEFT(F1,3) = ""Net"",$A$2*1.8,IF(F1=""F"",A1*1000,""""))"`

Comment: Another option: use `Option Compare Text` at the top of your module for always doing case insensitive comparisons.

Comment: Thank you everyone for the help!